# How to set UIButton on empty UIview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

i have already created multiple UIView and add and remove button on UIView
but i remove button on second index then after add new button so, new button is override on zero index like this

i have created 4 view and each view contain one button

my problem is when i remove button from particular view then button removed but when i again add button on same view, button add first view instead of same view

[image]

so how to add button on empty UIView

```
var width : CGFloat = 30
    func buttons() {

        answer =  ArrAnswer.objectAtIndex(k) as! String
        let letters : String = answer as String

        print(answer)
        strFinal = randomize(letters as String)

        for(i=0; i<strFinal?.characters.count; i++) {

            btn = UIButton()
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(width-10, 45, 40, 40)
            btn.tag = i
            print("btn TAG is : \(btn.tag)")
            ins = strFinal?.substringWithRange(i, location: 1)
            btn.setTitle(ins, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            btn.layer.cornerRadius = 0.2 * btn.bounds.size.width
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            btn.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
            btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)

            btn.addTarget(self, action: "button_click:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            width = width + 50
            if(i > 5) {
                if(i == 6) {
                    width = 40
                }

                btn.frame = CGRectMake(width-20, 95, 40, 40)
                width = width + 0
            }
            if(i > 11) {
                if(i == 12) {
                    width = 40
                }
                btn.frame = CGRectMake(width-20, 145, 40, 40)
                width = width + 0
            }

            answerButton .insert(btn, atIndex: i)
            //print(answerButton)
            viewButton.addSubview(btn)
        }
    }

    var btnwidth : CGFloat = 10

    func button_click(sender: UIButton) {

        for(i=0; i<strFinal?.characters.count; i++ ) {

            if sender.tag == i {
                sender.hidden = true

                button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton


                button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)

                ins = strFinal?.substringWithRange(i, location: 1)
                button.setTitle(ins, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                button.tag = i

                print("new button Tag: \(button.tag)")
                Arrtemp.addObject(ins!)
                print("button TAG : \(button.tag)")
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.2 * btn.bounds.size.width
                button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
                button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)

                //Spring Animation
                button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1)
                UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0,
                    delay: 0,
                    usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
                    initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,
                    animations: {
                        self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                    }, completion: nil)

                button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


                arrWidth[check].addSubview(button)

                check++

            }
        }
var viewwidth : CGFloat = 10
    func answerView() {

        let commonSpacing : CGFloat = 10
        let spaceSpacing : CGFloat = 35

        for(i=0; i<answer.characters.count; i++) {

            ansview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(viewwidth-5, 10, 30, 30))
            ansview.layer.cornerRadius = 0.2 * btn.bounds.size.width
            ansview.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            ansview.tag = i;
            arrWidth.append(ansview)

            viewAnswer.addSubview(ansview)

            viewwidth = viewwidth + 35

            let currCharacter = answer?[i]
            print(currCharacter)
            var tempSpacing = commonSpacing
            if currCharacter ==  " " {

                tempSpacing = spaceSpacing
            }
            viewwidth = ansview.frame.maxX + tempSpacing
        }

    }
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: You question is not clear. Please rephrase it to make it clear what are you asking. What do you mean by empty view? Do you mean nil view? Adding subview to view should not be giving you any trouble if you are giving the frame right. Secondly what do you mean it "overrides" button on 0 index. Only thing conspicuous there is the button on index 2.

Comment: i have created 4 view and each view contain one button got it...

Comment: We can see that. That still does not answer to what I asked you to clear.

Comment: my problem is when i remove button from particular view then button removed but when i again add button on same view, button add first view instead of same view

Comment: Hmm Okay. Please add this to your main question body. And I suspect that at some point your tags are messing up and thus you are adding subview to  wrong view. Tags are a messy way to go about your business. When you add it, I will remove my downvote.